# Append css to a class using a different class on the same element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to add `opacity: 1;` to the `.main` class (as itself, and not `.main.flow`) when `.flow` is added so that it can also affect `.main.secondary`.

Something similar to using mouse events (hover, active).

```css
.main {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main flow">
    <div class="not-main">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="main secondary">
</div>
```

I'm limited with the structure of the HTML as I'm just modding the CSS. Is this possible using only CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just have to select both the `.main.flow` and the other `.main` element relative to it.

Are the `.main` elements siblings, with the "flow" class being applied to the first of them?

If so:

```
.main {
    opacity: 0;
}

.main.flow, .main.flow + .main {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: how is for before `.main.flow`?

Comment: @ehsan: The asker said to assume that the "flow" class is applied to the first/primary .main element, so I did.

Comment: This works as needed but can you please explain how these selectors work? Because from what i understand `+` is used to select the following element to, in this case, `.main.flow`

Comment: @Explisam: .main.flow + .main selects the .main that comes after .main.flow, not the .main.flow itself. So you need two selectors in a comma-separated list to target both elements - and that's why the additional .main.flow is there.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.main {opacity:0;}
.main.flow {opacity:1;}
.main:not(.flow) {}
[class="main"] {opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="not-main">Main will be opaque because it has ONLY the main class</div>
</div>
<div class="main secondary">
  <div class="not-main">Main will be transparent because also has .secondary class</div>
</div>
<div class="main flow">
  <div class="not-main">Main flow would be transparent as well because it has more than just the main class, but it also has .main.flow that changes it to opaque.</div>
</div>
```

Just add them without a space:

```
.main.flow {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: This adds `opacity: 0;` to `.main.flow` class as a different class not `.main` as in particular, i want it added to `.main` when `.flow` exists.

Comment: This will add opacity:1 to an element with both the main AND the flow classes.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, i just want it added to `.main` as a separate class to affect other elements that has no `.flow` class.

Comment: @Jonathan , you edit your answer and copy my answer.

Comment: @Explisam - I'm reading your comment but not understanding, I think.  You can use .main:not(.flow) to affect element with the main class but NOT the flow class.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @ehsan I edited my answer to include a code snippet with my answer and Explisam's original code.  I posted the edit before I even saw your answer.

Comment: I understand what you're pointing at but to further explain it, i want `.flow` to affect any `.main` element that has no `.flow` class as well and not just `.main.flow`. That's why i want to append `opacity: 1` to `.main` as a standalone class.

Comment: Ok. That is exactly what '.not' will do: affect any div with the class .main that does NOT also have the .flow class.

Comment: Ah, so you want to have a class that will affect a div with ONLY the class main, correct?

Comment: @Jonathan: The same person has just done to me exactly what they accused you of. Ironic...

Answer (score 0):

If all elemens with class `.main` be after `.main.flow`, you can use this code:

```
.main.flow, .main.flow + .main {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Else, you can't do it with pure css, because css have not backward for this case you must help of jquery :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('.main.flow').length > 0)
    $('.main').css('opacity',1);
  else
    $('.main').css('opacity',0);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="main">
    <div class="not-main">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Explisam you can't do it with pure css.you are welcome.